# Check if string has any of List<string> values

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I have a class that has list of strings as a property:

```
public class FiltersDto
{
    public int? MinPrice { get; set; }

    public int? MaxPrice { get; set; }

    public int? BathroomCount { get; set; }

    public int? BedroomCount { get; set; }

    public string Amenities { get; set; }

    public List<string> Neighborhoods { get; set; }
}
```

In this method I try to check if the word "Neighborhood" is in the list

```
var sales = await
    _propertyRepository
        .GetAll()
        .Include(x => x.PropertyType)
        .WhereIf(input.Neighborhoods != null, x => x.Neighborhood.Contains(???????))
        .WhereIf(input.MinPrice.HasValue && input.MaxPrice.HasValue, x => input.MinPrice <= x.Price && x.Price <= input.MaxPrice)
        .WhereIf(input.BedroomCount.HasValue, x => x.BedroomCount == input.BedroomCount)
        .WhereIf(input.BathroomCount.HasValue, x => x.BathroomCount == input.BathroomCount)
        .Where(x => x.PropertyTypeId == 1)
        .ToListAsync();
```

I need to check it in this row `.WhereIf(input.Neighborhoods != null, x => x.Neighborhood.Contains(?))`

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell exactly form what is described, but if you have an instance of FiltersDto called `myFiltersDto` and it has a `.Neighborhoods` list like is like `{ "Red", "Blue", "Green"}` and your x's `.Neighborhood` string is `"Blah Red Sand"`

```
x => myFiltersDto.Neighbourhoods.Any(n => x.Neighborhood.Contains(n))
```

i.e. you're asking "do any of these `Neighborhoods n` appear within the string held in `x.Neighborhoods`"

If you don't intend for the `Contains` to be a within-string string search, and e.g. `x.Neighborhood` will merely be `"Red"` and you're seeking an exact match in the collection of strings represented by `Neighborhoods` then it's

```
x => myFiltersDto.Neighbourhoods.Contains(x.Neighborhood))
```

I'd recommend to try and avoid using the word "Contains" when describing this, because it generates confusion between `string.Contains` (substring search) and `list.Contains` (element search)

Comment: I need another, find is `Neighborhood` contains any from `Neighbourhoods`

So vice versa logic

Comment: *Neighborhood contains any from Neighbourhoods* - that's what I wrote - "the string `"Blah Red Sand"` contains any of the following text: `{"Blue","Red","Green"}`"; TRUE -> `"Blah Red Sand"` contains `"Red"`. If instead you mean like "the string `"Red"` is equal to any of the following: `{"Blue","Red","Green"}`", or said another way "the set of `{"Blue","Red","Green"}` contains `"Red"`" - that's the second example

Comment: @EugeneSukh - When you say `Neighborhood` contains any from `Neighborhoods` then you are saying `var Neighborhood = "I like apple pie"; var Neighborhoods = new [] { "apple", "banana" };` the would be `true`. Is that right?

Comment: @Enigmativity yes

Comment: Then that's the first code I posted...

Comment: Has this error when try to execute your code

The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Property>
    .Where(p => __ef_filter__p_0 || !(((ISoftDelete)p).IsDeleted))
    .Where(p => __input_Neighborhoods_0
        .Any(n => p.Neighborhood.Contains(n)))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable()